# How to put the difference of two files in another file

Tags: buffers

I have two files in two different buffers and I want to get the difference between these two files in another file

How can I do this with Vim?

Example:

**BUFFER1**

```
rtl.de
sat1.de
pro7.de
spiegel.de
```

**BUFFER2**

```
rtl.de
sat1.de
heise.de
pro7.de
spiegel.de
```

**buffer3**

```
heise.de
```

Answer (score 8):

Vim offers a tool to see the difference between two buffers and put contents from one to another: `diffthis` (see [`:h :diffthis`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#:diffthis)).

To get this diff mode you can either start it from the command line with:

```
$ vimdiff file1 file2
```

Or from within Vim:

- Open both of the buffers.
- create a split window to get both of the buffers on your screen. (with `:split` and `:e` for example)
- Start the diff mode with `:windo diffthis`
- Use `:diffput` and `:diffget` to modify the content of the buffers ([`:h :diffput`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#:diffput) and [`:h :diffget`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#:diffget)).
- Use `:diffoff` to stop the diff mode.

---

Now to put the diff of the files in a third one I would recommend to use the `diff` from the (shell) command line with something like (See [`man diff`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff)):

```
$diff file1 file2 > file3
```

From within Vim you can get the result of this command in a buffer with:

```
:read !diff file1 file2
```

`read` allows to get the result of a command in the current buffer and `!` allows to specify a string to be executed as an external command (here `diff file1 file2`)

Comment: this is so amazing! thanks so much for including the :diffthis command because rarely do i want to exit vim to run vimdiff if i already have the files/buffers opened!