# How can I edit a file and show a diff in a vertical split pane

Tags: vimdiff, scrolling

I have a program file `prog.pl` and a backup `prog.pl-20210615`.

At first they are identically. But then I want edit `prog.pl` and see the differences to the backupfile

| prog.pl | prog.pl-20210615 |
| --- | --- |
| text to edit ... | text to edit |
| abc def | abc def |

- How can I scroll both panes identically
- How can I recompare

If I move the cursor out of the screen, the right side scolls up but doesn't shows new lines.

`:diffupdate` doesn't work.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6951) or maybe [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/626)

Comment: @statox - Not really. I just want to edit my file and see the changes on the right pane. - Not need of getting changes back and so on.

Comment: And I want the line possition keep the same on both sides.

Comment: So you just want to use `:windo diffthis` like I show in the answer I linked, right? You don't need `:diffput` and `:diffget` but other than that it's the same. Or I don't understand the difference and it would be worth it the better explain what you want.

Comment: @statox You're right. I made an error tying the procedere on the answeres. And then I needed the `rR` command to unfold all (cause I have to edit one of the files). - Please set your comment as answere, so I can accept it.

Comment: I'll vote to close it as a duplicate instead to keep the site clean and keep limited sources of truth for the future readers :)